# Azure Powershell: Unable to find environment with name 'AzureCloud' on self-hosted azure devops agent

Tags: azure-devops, azure-powershell, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I have suddenly started getting this error on some of the agents that are installed on my Agent Pool. All of them are on the same Virtual Machine:

```
2022-06-13T11:07:24.5665998Z ##[command]"C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'D:\Agent\02\_work\_temp\3c5c143c-117b-4adb-9c90-7043632edfa0.ps1'"
2022-06-13T11:07:26.0076950Z Added TLS 1.2 in session.
2022-06-13T11:07:26.1347095Z ##[command]Import-Module -Name C:\Program Files\PowerShell\Modules\Az.Accounts\2.8.0\Az.Accounts.psd1 -Global
2022-06-13T11:07:26.8410918Z ##[command]Clear-AzContext -Scope CurrentUser -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
2022-06-13T11:07:27.4110901Z ##[command]Clear-AzContext -Scope Process
2022-06-13T11:07:27.4789914Z ##[command]Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant {{Redacted}} -Credential System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -Environment AzureCloud @processScope
2022-06-13T11:07:27.5295739Z ##[error]Unable to find environment with name 'AzureCloud'
2022-06-13T11:07:27.6855841Z ##[error]There was an error with the service principal used for the deployment.
2022-06-13T11:07:27.7936958Z ##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
2022-06-13T11:07:29.5169529Z ##[command]Disconnect-AzAccount -Scope Process -ErrorAction Stop
2022-06-13T11:07:29.9206643Z ##[command]Clear-AzContext -Scope Process -ErrorAction Stop
```

I have tried uninstalling and installing azure powershell, but the error persist. Also agents which are using the same service connection on a different VM are deploying without any issues.

Finally I tried to run the command locally on my VM and it succeeded, so I am not sure what could be causing this error.

Answer (score 3):

We experience the same error message.

In our case, we ran out of space.
Therefore, the solution is to clean up the system disk.

The real problem was not the missing space, but corrupted files in the folder
**$env:HOMEPATH\.Azure** of the user of DevOps Agent.

There can more options on how to fix it.
We decided to simply delete the folder **$env:HOMEPATH\.Azure** and let the mechanism create **.Azure** folder again own way after retry of failing job(s).

Comment: You are a life saver.. After the system disk got full, and we cleared space, the pipelines were still not working. Deleting the ".Azure" folder in the HOMEPATH did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it may cause by Azure PowerShell Module.

You could try uninstall the Az PowerShell module locally on your VM : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/uninstall-az-ps?view=azps-8.0.0

And re-install for "AllUsers" scope:

```
Install-Module -Name Az -Scope AllUsers -Repository PSGallery -Force
```

Comment: I tried doing this and I still had the same issue. I also tried using -AllowClobber, but the result was the same.